# Loading Docusign Focus View on web android Not working for the first time

Tags: docusignapi

am working on using Focused View in my platform by using docusign JS Library.
it works fine on Web Browser on Desktop.
but on Android Web Browser it is not working for the first time.

it loads a blank View
[Blank frame for docusign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYdj4.png)
[console errors and warnings (have the same error and warnings on desktop and it works fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IdQp.png)
any suggestions please ?

if i refresh the page or navigate to another page and back again it will work.

when i disabled cache it didn't work again at all.

i believe it is something related to loading inner js files inside the library which i dont have control to load earlier

Answer (score 0):

I would advise opening a case on the DocuSign support site to investigate this issue with you. https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US